# What's wrong with my string formatting?

Tags: python

So I'm completely new to Python and I've made only JS and PHP so far.

So I have this code

```
    """Shutdown code"""
timeToShutdown = input("Time to shutdown: ")

import os

os.system("shutdown /s /t %d") % timeToShutdown
```

It does not work like that (doesn't do anything),

It only works like this

```
"""Shutdown code"""
#timeToShutdown = input("Time to shutdown: ")

import os

os.system("shutdown /s /t 7200")
```

So what is wrong in inputting the number as variable.

PS: I've tried `int(input())` too.

Comment: use `%s` in place of  `%d` because `input()` always returns text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to format the string, not the return. ie, move your `%` to inside the brackets:

```
os.system("shutdown /s /t %s" % timeToShutdown)
                           ^ input() returns a string not a number
```